# Why does this oneliner give me an error?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I am writting this oneliner and it gives me an error like syntax error, unexpected end of file. I want it to be an oneliner and to delete all files that have .c extension found in folder "uso". Thank you!

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in $(find uso | grep "[.][c]$"); do rm -rf $file done
```

Comment: Perhaps simply `find uso -name '*.c' -exec rm -f {} \;` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a semi-colon at the end.

```
for file in $(find uso | grep "[.][c]$"); do rm -rf $file; done
```

A better way to do this, by the way, is:

```
find uso -name '*.c' -delete             # GNU find
find uso -name '*.c' -exec rm -f {} \;   # POSIX find
```

These will safely handle directory and file names containing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a add the missing semicolon before the done,

for file in $(find uso | grep "[.][c]$"); do rm -rf $file ; done

like the line above.